# Estado HTTP 500. Error interno del servidor

Tags: java

Intento cargar una pagina web pero me sale el siguiente error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: La clase 'org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl' no tiene la propiedad 'req'.
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Algún consejo?

Comment: tengo este error org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: La clase 'org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl' no tiene la propiedad 'req'.

Comment: Por el nombre req supongo que has querido poner Request o por ahí va la cosa. Revisa bien tu JSP. Raro que la compilación no lo detecte. Debe ser el index.jsp de ControlClientes. Busca en la página donde utilizas: req y verifica que está correctamente definido.

Comment: esta definido y aun así me da el error.

Comment: Puedes  mostrarnos esa pagina?

Comment: /*este es el codigo que se encuentra en mi clase index.jsp alli hago un refresh al ServletControlador */  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=${pageContext.reques.contextPath}/ServletControlador">

Comment: es pageContext.reques  o pageContext.request.

Comment: asi pageContext.reques ...con reques debido a que asi lo tengo definido en mi ServletControlador.y aun asi no encuentro el error @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest reques, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException  {
        List<Cliente> clientes =new ClienteDaoJDBC().listar();
        System.out.println("clientes = " + clientes);
        reques.setAttribute("clientes", clientes);
        reques.getRequestDispatcher("clientes.jsp").forward(reques, resp);
    }

Comment: sera que tengo que volver a rediseñar todas las clases de inicio??

Comment: En la etiqueta <meta> no  tiene nada que  ver con los parametros del servidor, En tu Servlet puedes tener pepito si quieres pero no puedes usar ese nombre en el <meta> porque alli estás invocando al PageContext, Prueba  poniendo  la t en el meta

Comment: No. en los JSP para hacer  referencia a variable del servidor por ejemplo en tu  caso  para  invocar a  ServetControlador necesitas tener  el path  hacia él. Como  consigues ese path pues utilizan pageContext,request,.contextPath  que es propio del JSP. Hasta ese punto tu  Controlador ni siquiera se ha invocado.

Comment: Tu parametro  reques es donde vas a recibir el HttpServletRequest. Pero sólo es valido en ese ambito. Por eso el error te dice que PageContext no tiene esa  propiedad. Si tienes  varias paginas igual lo unico que tienes que hacer  el ponerle la t final.